# How o batch rename file using another file with the same uniqe prefix?

Tags: regex, shell, terminal, rename, batch-rename

## Problem

Given lots of files with a dedicated unique prefix.

I'd like to replace each filename of them with the filename of a related file which starts with the same unique prefix.

## Example

### input:

```
- UUIDa.txt
- UUIDa_apple.md

- UUIDb.txt
- UUIDb_orange.md

- UUIDc.txt
- UUIDc_banana.md
```

### output:

```
- UUIDa_apple.txt
- UUIDa_apple.md

- UUIDb_orange.txt
- UUIDb_orange.md

- UUIDc_banana.txt
- UUIDc_banana.md
```

```
- UUIDa.txt
- UUIDa_apple.md

prefix -> UUIDa
add "_apple" after UUIDa -> UUIDa_apple
```

[git-diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbTvP.png)

Comment: Can you clarify how you define 'prefix' ? - is it all the letters up to '_' ?

Comment: I've modified the question, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Have you written any code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything up to the underscore _ is considered the UUID, this works:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.md; do
    echo $file;
    EXT="${file##*.}"
    FILENAME="${file%.*}"
    UUID="${file%_*}"
    if [ -f "${UUID}.txt" ]; then
        mv "${UUID}.txt" "${FILENAME}.txt"
        echo "renamed ${UUID}.txt to ${FILENAME}.txt"
    fi
done
```

This does not traverse directories, but only works on the current directory.